# Isotopes and electron transitions

Tags: electrons, atomic-physics, orbitals, isotopes

Do neutrons in the nucleus (isotopes) affect the frequency of electron transitions through valence shells?

Comment: The main contribution of this really negligible change can be handled by reduced mass method.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent that isn't correct. In fact, this "negligible" change underlies the atomic clock and our definition of the second through nuclear hyperfine splitting of electron levels.

Comment: @KFGauss already gave you the upvote. It might not be totally negligible, but it is definitely a small perturbation.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Yes, definitely agree with you that it's tiny compared to the bare Coulomb interaction. But being negligible depends on the context. GPS navigation wouldn't work without this effect after all. So getting it exactly right is not just a matter of stamp collecting.

Answer (score 16):

Yes, the neutron number in atomic isotopes cause changes in electron energy levels through several main effects:

1. A different mass for the core, which results in shifts to all energy levels. This mass effect can be understood to arise from a different kinetic energy of the nucleus as it interacts with the electron. These shifts can be on the order of hundreds of MHz or larger.
2. Change in the charge distribution of the nucleus - the "Volume effect". The addition of neutrons can broaden the charge distribution of the nucleus which makes it less like an idealized point charge. This effect is really only relevant for heavy nuclei.
3. Hyperfine splitting of energy levels. The number of neutrons changes the nuclear spin, which couples to the electron through the the magnetic hyperfine interaction. These splittings are usually on the scale of 1-10 GHz. **This effect is arguably the most important of all three.**

#3 is especially interesting in ultracold atom systems, where the nuclear spin will dictate if the atom has fermion or boson statistics. On the practical side, the precision and stability of hyperfine splittings forms the basis of the atomic clock and GPS navigation.

For molecules and solid state electrons, mainly #1 and #3 are relevant. The number of neutrons changes the vibrational structure and magnetic coupling. These changes can be observed on macroscopic scales, as heavier nuclei can change the superconducting transition temperature, or in the case of liquid Helium-3, completely change its properties and give rise to new phases of matter.

Comment: Perhaps I am extrapolating in the wrongs way but wouldn't this mean that if a Cesium atom used in an atomic clock gained a neutron, It would play havoc with human time measurements.

Thank you for your answers. I appreciate it.

Comment: Yes you are right, which is why we specifically use Cs-133 for atomic clocks. It is straightforward to identify and throw out Cs atoms with the wrong number of neutrons based on the effects listed above.

Comment: This is a great answer, but in light atomic systems, #1 is actually more important than #3. For example, in hydrogen, mass and hyperfine effects scale as ${\cal{O}}(m/M_\text{nuc})$ and ${\cal{O}}(\alpha^2m/M_\text{nuc})$, respectively. Also, energy differences associated with fermion/boson statistics are not directly related to #3: hfs arises from the higher EM moments of the nucleus like magnetic dipole, or electric quadrupole moments (basically a combination of your #3 and #2), while statistics affect the energy by dictating the permutational behaviour of the wave function.